# Where did this $ne come from for this find method?

Tags: meteor

Given the following Meteor code helper from the websites "Try Meteor" tutorial:

```
// Add to Template.body.helpers
incompleteCount: function () {
   return Tasks.find({checked: {$ne: true}}).count();
}
```

I get pretty much everything about this code except for this arbitrary looking `$ne` thing. I've seen this before with Meteor examples and I don't get it: What does `$ne` represent? Where did `$ne` come from?

Comment: `$ne` means "not equal to". In this case, it's finding `Task` objects that are not `checked`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`$ne` means not equal to.

It is preferable to use this instead of `{checked: false}` since it also includes the ones where the `checked` attribute isn't in the document `{}` and the case where `{checked: null}` as both of these are cases where `checked` isn't equal to `true` & are also not `false`.

This way if you have a fresh document without any attributes it would also be a result of the query.

Comment: Is this a Meteor thing or a Mongo thing? I'm just wondering where I can find all available options to study them.

Comment: Its a mongo thing. Check out http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ for all the operators